# JAVA: Printing number of different integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with a number of integers in it. Now I want to print the number of these integers that are different.

If I have `int[] arr = {1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5};` I want to print something like this: `Sum=5`. As there are 5 distinct integers in the array.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far with your code?

Comment: The sum of what is 5?

Comment: sum should be 5 or 15 ??

Comment: Sum of different intigers in an array. I don't want to print 1+2+3+4+5 but I want to print how many different intigers are in this array.

Comment: You need to learn about programming basics such as looping.

Comment: Not much, I'm trying with for and if but no results so far

Comment: You probably need to filter out duplicates.  Then you probably need to count how many there are.

Comment: One way(as there are many), to use a collection which does not allow duplicates(Like implementation of set). Then iterate over it for summation. I can provide you the code if you need.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using Java 8 streams would look like this

```
int[] arr = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5};
long count = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count();
System.out.format("Sum=%d\n", count);
```

The result for the array in your question is 5.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a count without duplicates. Simple answer is to use a Set

```
Integer[] myArr = {1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5};
System.out.println("Sum = " + new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArr)).size());
```

Comment: The size is not the sum, but I guess this is correct based on what OP says.